# Crash during Fragment transactions inside the Custom Dialog in Xamarin Android

Tags: mono, xamarin.android, xamarin, monodroid.dialog

When i tried to add a fragment inside a dialog, the app got crash. The crash saying "No View found for ID 0x01276"

This is the layout file for Dialog (my_dialog_layout.axml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the code for opening the dialog and for fragment transaction

```
class CustomDialog : Dialog{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState)

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.dialog_fragment_layout);

        var myCustomFragmnent = new MyCustomFragment(_context);

        // Start Fragment Transaction Process
        var transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

        // Here is a crash saying (No View found for ID 0x01276....)
        transaction.Add(Resource.Id.fragment_container, myCustomFragmnent);

        transaction.Commit();             
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you don't need to use a "heavy" layout such as `LinearLayout`, I suggest you use `FrameLayout` for your container.

Secondly, try to use `transaction.Replace` instead. Also make sure that `MyCustomFragment` does not blow up in `OnCreateView`. It might be where your problem lies as you didn't post the full stack trace.

When using `transaction.Replace` you can have it handle the backstack for you by adding:

```
transaction.AddToBackStack(null);
```

after your `Replace` call, such that when you press the back button on your phone it navigates back to the previous `Fragment` shown.